# Strange issue with NSTableView when using Full Size Content View on OSX

Tags: macos, cocoa

I have been stuck with this for hours with no luck

I want to set Full Size Content View on my Window Controller like this

[image]

To achieve this transparent title bar like that

[image]

Everything works ok but my NSTableView fills begin of the table with blank rows and selection does not works, like this

[image]

Any ideas on how to fix that? Any comment or help will be much welcome!

Comment: Does it work when you swich Full Size Content View off?

Comment: Yes it works perfectly @Willeke